# Remove internal sub domain duplicate content on Google

Tags: seo, web-hosting, 301-redirect, duplicate-content, google-index

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Remove URLs from Google Search Engine](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8487/how-to-remove-urls-from-google-search-engine)

*Our hosting provider has a internal sub domain like so:* `n265-269-265-265.cnet.hosting.iiii`.

The internal sub domain is redirected to our registered domain and is publicly available. Google indexed the internal domain content and now it is appearing on search pages. We'd like it if Google removed the internal sub domain content and we would like to setup a redirect to the main domain.

Our hosting provider is actually a sub-provider and as far as we know it does not fully control the main hosting domain and I am stuck in a discussion with them about what can be done. I would like a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove content from google by using Google webmaster tools, see [this page](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=164734) on Google which should help you to answer your query.

You will need to register your subdomain with webmaster tools and authorise it before you can remove it but it's a very easy process.

The other thing you may want to consider is adding a [canonical URL](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-url-canonicalization/) to the page, this way Google will know that the URL should be the proper one and not the subdomain.

Comment: That's not our domain. The main domain is of our hosting provider.

Comment: You should still be able to register the directory that your files are in

Comment: Looks like I solved this issue with .htaccess:<pre>RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(exact-subdomain-inside this bracket)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=410,L]</pre>